# Create user notification system in Django

Tags: django-models, django-authentication, django-socialauth

I am adding a system to leave "notifications" for users that can be displayed the next time they log in. I created a simple Notification class in the models.py file. I have this UserInfo class (in the same models.py) to add on some attributes to Django's existing user system as part of socialauth:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    ...
    reputation = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def add_notification(message):
        notification = Notification(user=self.user, message=message)
        notification.save
```

When I try it out in the console I end up with this:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(id=14)
>>> user.userinfo.add_notification('you are an awesome intern!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add_notification() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>>
```

What am I missing here? I'm kind of a Django noob so maybe it's something easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Use Django messages

First off, please consider [dcrodjer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229044/create-user-notification-system-in-django/4229088#4229088). The Django message system is exactly what you need, and why put in your code tree something that you get for free?

(Of course, if you're doing this just to experiment and learn more about Django, please continue!)

---

## Anyway, a fix

Summary: To fix this, just change `add_notifications` to this:

```
    def add_notification(self, message):
        notification = Notification(user=self.user, message=message)
        notification.save
```

Note the additional argument (named `self`) in the method signature.

---

## Why it's not working

There's a bit of a quirk in calling methods in Python.

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print 'Calling bar'

    def baz(self, shrubbery):
        print 'Calling baz'

thisguy = Foo()
```

When you call the method `bar`, you can use a line like `thisguy.bar()`. Python sees that you're calling a method on an object (a method called `bar` on an object called `thisguy`). When this happens, Python fills in the first argument of the method with the object itself (the `thisguy` object).

The reason your method doesn't work is that you are calling `userinfo.add_notification('you are an awesome intern!')` on a method that is only expecting one argument. Well, Python has already filled in the first argument (named `message`) with the `userinfo` object. Thus, Python complains that you're passing two arguments to a method that only expects one.

Answer (score 11):

Use the django message framework:  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/
You may put the userinfo stored messages in queue as soon as he logs in using this:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
```

Comment: I'm looking to have a notification system where notifications persist until they are closed by a user via an ajax call, kind of like on Stack Overflow. Do you think messages can do this?

Comment: yeah...i guess messages is a pretty nice feature...i too use it...you should consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229044/create-user-notification-system-in-django/4229263#4229263).

Answer (score 3):

add_notification is a method on a class. That means it implicitly gets passed the instance of the class as the first parameter. [Classes in Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes)

Try this instead:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    def add_notification(self, message):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should perhaps update your question if you're looking for persistent messaging. Maybe https://github.com/philomat/django-persistent-messages can help you save coding time?

Comment: Does persistent messaging also mean live notifications. As in the notification will pop up on user's screen after it is created?